# How do I change the link color and background hover with css when it's inside a div tag?

Tags: html, css, hyperlink, hover

this is an example:

```
#dolls {
position: absolute;
left: 248px;
top: 31px;
width: 150px;
height: 65px;
z-index: 2;
text-align: center;
color: #8C6954;
font-size: 18px;
text-decoration:none;

<div id="dolls"><br><a href="dolls.html">Haunted Dolls</a></div>
```

I'm trying to change the color of the link, hover and background color on hover, but it won't work. How do I do this?

Comment: have you tried doing a 'css for dummies' tutorial? It's written for a reason... And this is a very, very basic question.

Answer (score 2):

Use `a:hover` to apply hover effect

```css
#dolls {
  position: absolute;
  left: 248px;
  top: 31px;
  width: 150px;
  height: 65px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  color: #8C6954;
  font-size: 18px;
  text-decoration: none;
}
div a:hover {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<div id="dolls">
  <br><a href="dolls.html">Haunted Dolls</a>
</div>
<a href="anotherLink">Some other link</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use pseudo classes `hover` and `link`

```
a:hover {
// css code
}

a:link {
// css code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

**CSS**

```
#dolls a:hover{
    color:white;
    background:red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put `#dolls` in front of `a:hover {` to only make the `a`'s in `#dolls` get the hover effect.

```
#dolls a:hover {
    color:blue; // color of text
    background-color: green; // background color
}
```